# Using renewal-reward theory to find long-run proportions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, expected-value, renewal-processes

[image]

Intuitively, it should just be $\frac{E[A]}{E[A] + E[B] + E[C]}$ as in the long-run, since the probabilities of picking the bulb are symmetric, each bulb will be used the same number of times. How do I formalize this using renewal-reward theory?

I would like to define a renewal as when a bulb burns out. Then a cycle is the time between $2$ bulbs burning out. If I can find the expected length of a cycle, then I am done.

If we have bulb $A$ right before a renewal, then with probability $1/2$ bulb $B$ is chosen with a lifetime of $E[B]$ and with probability $1/2$ bulb $C$ is chosen with a lifetime of $E[C]$. Thus the expected length of the cycle, given that we start with bulb $A$, is $\frac{E[B] + E[C]}{2}$. Similar reasoning works if we start with bulbs $B$ or $C$. But how do I use this to find the expected cycle length?

Comment: The times when bulbs burn out are not true renewals because it does not reset the system to the same state (it depends on which bulb burned out). Instead, you could define a renewal as the start of a new type $A$ bulb.  Then the fraction of time using type $A$ is $\frac{E[A]}{E[A] + E[Remaining]}$ where $E[Remaining]$ is the remaining time until we get back to type $A$.  You can then calculate $E[Remaining]$.  The final answer will support your original intuition.